# OS X: log text from serial port

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, serial-port, pipe

I have a text stream coming in on a USB-RS232 adapter. I want to pipe it to some Unix tools, to a file, whatever. What is the simplest way to do so? Does it really require third-party software?

OS X includes `cu` and `screen` utilities, but both are specialized terminal emulators. It seems I need to use `sudo` to make `cu` work at all, which isn't really cool.

I saw something somewhere about OS X Server having a serial port logging facility. Is that an exclusive feature?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `cat < /dev/ttyS0 > outputfile` or `cat < /dev/ttyS0 | command`? Your serial port may be named something else like `/dev/usbXXX`. You may need to set the communication parameters using `stty`.

Comment: For one thing, the baud rate needs to be specified. That is probably the first thing I tried.

Comment: Also, `stty` does not appear to work at all on this device.